Why is this frame.onload not triggered?
I have a web page that calls an onload method myonload as a final line in the <script> section of the header:
...
<head>
...
<script>
var frame;

function loadthis(e,pg) {
    // 50 line method to set frame.src according to different conditions
    if...
        frame.src = pg;
    else...
        frame.src = ...
}

function myonload() {
    frame = document.getElementById("MainFrame")
    frame.onload = function(e) { ... }
    ...

    var frm = "https://mydefaultpage.html";
    var parameters = window.location.search.substring(1).split("?");
    var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
    if (temp.length > 1) {
       frm = unescape(temp[1]);
       document.getElementById("loader-wrapper").style.display = "block";
       loadthis("null",frm);
    } else {
       loadthis(88,frm);
    }
}

window.onload = myonload;
</script>
</head>
<body>
....
<div id="MainFrameDiv">
 <iframe id="MainFrame" name="MainFrame"></iframe>
</div>
</body>

The document has an iframe called MainFrame. As shown above, inside myonload, I have a function that checks if this iframe is loaded with
function myonload() {
    frame = document.getElementById("MainFrame")
    frame.onload = function(e) { ... }
    ...
}

Everything works as expected, except that the frame.onload is NOT triggered when I press the browser refresh button. It does work if I refresh the page with Ctrl-Shift-R, though.
Now, if I replace
 window.onload = myonload;

with
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myonload);

the thing seems to work well.
Why is that, and how to handle the refresh properly?

Are you pressing Control-Shift-R? or just Control-r? The former prevents using the cache, which could make a difference.

It's not a cache problem. I tried with frame.src=....?dummy=RANDOMNUMBER and the problem persisted.

Why not just use the second method? ti’s much more reliable.

I am using it, but I want to understand what is happening.

How is the iframe appended into the doc and how/when is its src set? If its through the parser (i.e. its part of the HTML markup), then it should never work since the global onload is supposed to wait for the iframe's one. If it's dynamic, then show how it's done exactly as that's where you'd want to hook.

@Kaiido My web page P has a menu at the left, and the iframe F at its right. According to the menu button clicked on P, or to P URL parameters gave to the browser (?=parameter), F.src is loaded by the initial script. The F code is attached at the end of the html code of P, without the .src. I edited my original post showing this.

Ok, so the src is set dynamically by a script, can you please show that?
